# No response to create new project on Win7

Tags: meteor

I just installed Meteor on my Win7 by 0.5.4.msi and rebooted it. I can find the Meteor folder in environment path. But when I try to create my first app in cmd, nothing happened, no success or fail information.[image] Any suggestions?

Comment: Did nothing happen or did it just not show a response? Is there now a "myTest" folder at C:\?

Comment: Sometimes this happens when node has some kind of issue

Comment: @Rahul Just nothing happened, either in the console or the file system. BTW my system is 64bit. I'm not sure if that matters.

Comment: @Akshat Could you give some suggestions? Both Node.js and meteor are new to me.

Comment: Try running the command on D:\ .. sometimes users don't have rights to create folders in the root drive.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command on D:\ .. sometimes users don't have rights to create folders in the root drive.

Comment: This is probably better as a comment, since it's a suggestion to try something. "Maybe this will work; you should try it" isn't really an answer.

Comment: What is the convention here .. I put suggestion in the comments and if it works .. I add it as the answer? Shouldn't a "possible answer" be more prominent than a comment?

Comment: @Mubix I'm the administration account and the machine only has the C disk. Anyway thanks for your attention.